# Netty 4 io.netty.channel.PartialFlushException after write

Tags: netty

On a second .write on a new channel in my code, `ChannelFuture.isSuccess` for the write operation is false, and the `ChannelFuture.cause` is `io.netty.channel.PartialFlushException: 0 out of 1 message(s) flushed`. I have little idea what should be done to avoid this, and where to look for the deeper root cause.

ChannelFuture.cause.getStackTraceString is:

> io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundMessageHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundMessageHandlerAdapter.java:118)
>   io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:237)
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:1308)
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.write0(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:1445)
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.write(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:1412)
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.write(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:1034)
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.write(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:959)
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.write(AbstractChannel.java:246)
>   pipe.Broker$writer$.write(Broker.scala:72)
>   pipe.Broker$httpClientHandler.messageReceived(Broker.scala:57)
>   pipe.Broker$httpClientHandler.messageReceived(Broker.scala:52)
>   io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter.inboundBufferUpdated(ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter.java:104)
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeInboundBufferUpdated(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:951)
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireInboundBufferUpdated0(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:926)
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireInboundBufferUpdated(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:904)
>   io.netty.handler.codec.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:466)
>   io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.inboundBufferUpdated(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:69)
>   io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundByteHandlerAdapter.inboundBufferUpdated(ChannelInboundByteHandlerAdapter.java:51)
>   io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.inboundBufferUpdated(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:194)
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeInboundBufferUpdated(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:951)
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireInboundBufferUpdated0(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:926)
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireInboundBufferUpdated(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:904)
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireInboundBufferUpdated(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:909)
>   io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:115)
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:401)
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:365)
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:302)
>   io.netty.channel.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:110)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

The first .write on the channel goes well (isSuccess is true, and indeed the written message perfectly arrives and parses at its destination). But the second .write consistently fails as described.

The second .write is issued from within my overridden ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter.[messageReceived](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter.html#messageReceived%28io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext,%20I%29) method once it receives acknowledgement for the receipt of the first .write by the remote peer.

My code that performs the actual write (this is Scala) is:

```
 request = new DefaultHttpRequest(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpMethod.GET, "/"+msg)
              var writeFuture = channel.write(request).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener(){
                  def operationComplete(channelFuture: ChannelFuture){
                    if (channelFuture.isSuccess)
                        println("write finished successfully")
                    else 
                        println ("write failed: " + channelFuture.cause + "\n" + channelFuture.cause.getStackTraceString)
                  }
              })
```

What can be the problem and how should it be traced?

Comment: Note that the accepted answer suggests the way to look at the more 'root' cause of the failure, by using the more verbose printStackTrace method or using .cause.getCause on the future. It answers to the need to trace the problem (albeit no solution to the root problem found yet - unless answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097966/unexpected-message-type-defaulthttprequest-on-a-httpclientcodec-pipeline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `PartialFlushException` contains the actual cause of the flush failure.  You can get it using `Exception.getCause()` method that Java provides:

```
PartialFlushException e = ...;
e.getCause(); // This will return the exception you raised.
```

To get the complete information of an exception, instead of printing an exception, you have to call `printStackTrace()`.

```
future.cause.printStackTrace()
```

For more information about chained exceptions, please refer to [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/chained.html).

Comment: Thanks. My code is currently using .cause on the channel future to get the cause text. That seems to return PartialFlushException's cause text "0 out of 1 message(s) flushed". I am rather clueless how to interpret this as a root cause. What can I be missing? BTW trying to wrap the write operation in a try block doesn't yield catching the exception in a catch block, probably due to the asynchronous nature of write. So I just assume that the .cause coming on the channel future is the way to get the exception, and indeed it's a PartialFlushException with the cause text that I just mentioned.

Comment: The problem is, that cause text is hard for me to interpret in any actionable way.

Comment: PartialFlushException.getCause() will return another exception that is the root cause.

Comment: Thanks, using channelFuture.cause.getCause obviously indeed goes one level deeper, where the cause is revealed as 'unexpected message type: DefaultHttpRequest'. Not sure yet why that type of object is not valid/expected, given that the pipeline is purely a HttpRequestEncoder! but that's already a question for a differently titled topic... I'm closing this one. If you'd like to comment why isn't an HttpRequestEncoder expected on an Http pipeline here, please don't hold yourself off ;)