# unexpected message type: DefaultHttpRequest, on a HttpClientCodec pipeline

Tags: netty

A second `.write` on the channel, results in an exception

> "io.netty.handler.codec.CodecException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected message type: DefaultHttpRequest".

Scratching my head what should be done differently, given that the pipeline only has `HttpClientCodec` on it. Reproduces by cloning from [Github](https://github.com/cloudaloe/pipe) and running main, which runs the client and server sides, reproducing the error.

Comment: Which "main" needs to get run to reproduce ?

Comment: runner.main, which is found inside [main.scala](https://github.com/cloudaloe/pipe/blob/master/src/main/scala/main.scala).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write a `DefaultFullHttpResponse`. `DefaultHttpResponse` lacks content and `HttpContent`s and a `LastHttpContent` must follow.  I agree this is confusing indeed.

Comment: I think you meant I should have used DefaultFullHttpRequest instead of DefaultHttpRequest - indeed switching to use  `DefaultFullHttpRequest` seems to solve the problem (and now a new warning on the server side: Discarded 1 inbound message(s) that reached at the end of the pipeline. Please check your pipeline configuration.").